# how to use simple formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

```
=SUM(IF(R4>D4;(D4*$D$2)*1000;(R4*$D$2)*1000)+IF(S4>E4;(E4*$E$2)*1000;(S4*$E$2)*1000)+IF(T4>F4;(F4*$F$2)*1000;(T4*$F$2)*1000)+IF(U4>G4;(G4*$G$2)*1000;(U4*$G$2)*1000)+IF(V4>H4;(H4*$H$2)*1000;(V4*$H$2)*1000)+IF(W4>I4;(I4*$I$2)*1000;(W4*$I$2)*1000)+IF(X4>J4;(J4*$J$2)*1000;(X4*$J$2)*1000)+IF(Y4>K4;(K4*$K$2)*1000;(Y4*$K$2)*1000)+IF(Z4>L4;(L4*$L$2)*1000;(Z4*$L$2)*1000))
```

please help me for this formula to simple formula

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking here. If you can clarify what problem you're trying to solve and give a bit more detail about the formula you've provided someone may be able to help :)

Comment: One simplification you can make is to remove every instance of `*1000` and put that instead at the end of the formula.

Comment: i guess you just want to simplify the formula you posted, am i right?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very long formula. First, the semicolons need to be just commas.  If you were trying to simplify this mess, you could have made a more simple formula in cell D6 =min(R4,D4)*D2*1000 and copy that formula to E6:L6. Then you would sum that range in row 6 =sum(D6:L6).  The absolute reference isn't needed for your row 2 items ($D$2).

Comment: "the semicolons need to be just commas" is not necessarily true, the separator depends on the regional settings of the machine. For example in Italy (i'm italian) the separator is the semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an array formula (some docs from microsoft [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) and [here](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d)).
Basically it works with array of values instead single cells, it's less "intuitive" but very powerful. Also the `*1000` could be done just one time (for the [distributive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property)). A formula like this

```
=sum(if(r4:z4>d4:l4;d4:l4*d2:l2;r4:z4*d2:l2))*1000
```

should work.
**Note:** The array formulas are inserted as regular formulas **but** instead pressing *return* for confirm you must use *Ctrl+shift+return*. Doing this, excel adds an opening and a closing braket to the formula: so you write the formula as above, you press *ctrl+shift+return* and excel will write in the cell a formula like this

```
={sum(if(r4:z4>d4:l4;d4:l4*d2:l2;r4:z4*d2:l2))*1000}
```

so, **do not write the brakets**, excel will do.